# Update records in a loop performance in c# and sql

Tags: c#, sql, performance, foreach

I need to update 100 records in database from my application in C#.

I have used a foreach statement and called a stored procedure to update each records like this:

```
foreach (var record in recordList)
{  
    dbWatch.Start();
    DbService.UpdateRecord(Id, ProcessDate, MessageID, task.Result.Email.TryTimes);
    dbWatch.Stop();
    LogMessage(string.Format("Single database row update toke:{0}",dbWatch.Elapsed));
}
```

Everything is working fine except that when its starts, it's taking about 00:00:00.00123343 to update each record, but as its going to update more and more, it takes more and more. After almost 1000 records it take about 00:00:04 seconds to update each records.

I'm wondering why it's like that?

Comment: What is dbWatch? Does it have to be reset before you call .Start()?

Comment: Given that your recordList may have come from another query, if possible, look for ways to do one update rather than bringing data back to your application and looping through it.

Comment: Btw, is it desired that you're never using the loop variable `record` to update the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume this is just an incorrect measurement. Your loop does not restart the `StopWatch`, it just starts and stops it consecutively. So `Elapsed` will always increase.

If you want to measure the entire time:

```
dbWatch.Start();
foreach (var record in recordList)
{  
    DbService.UpdateRecord(Id, ProcessDate, MessageID, task.Result.Email.TryTimes);
}
dbWatch.Stop();
LogMessage(string.Format("All updates took:{0}",dbWatch.Elapsed));
```

If you want to measure the time for each iteration use [`StopWatch.Restart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart.aspx):

```
foreach (var record in recordList)
{  
    dbWatch.Restart();
    DbService.UpdateRecord(Id, ProcessDate, MessageID, task.Result.Email.TryTimes);
    dbWatch.Stop();
    LogMessage(string.Format("Single database row update took:{0}",dbWatch.Elapsed));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to call `dbWatch.Reset()` at the end of the loop or `Restart()` at the beginning if you want to measure the time of each Update. I assume its a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.
See [MSDN - Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch_methods.aspx).